# Apache spark shuffle : Why we do re-sort on reducer side even after sorting on mapping side

Tags: apache-spark

Lately i wanted to understand how spark use Sort shuffle. I found that spark sorts the mapper side and then resort the same thing on reducer side using tim sort.

If we are already sorting on mapper side why we are not reusing that inplace of re-sorting, considering sorting is costly ?

Note : Tim sort take sorted list to work up on.

Answer (score 0):

In the reducer side, the `BlockStoreShuffleReader` fetches shuffle data from multiple map tasks. Although the map tasks sorted their own data, as the reducer needs to merge data from multiple sources, it has to resort for a combined sort among all the data fetched.